# Setting minimum date on other date picker relevant to another date picker

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I know that this may have been asked before, but I cant find a solution for my problem. I have two DatePickerDialogs in which, whenever the start date is set, i'll set the minimum date of the other datepickerdialog to that date. But it is still not working becuase the minimum date of the enddatepicker is the same as the startdatepicker. Here's my code for reference :

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    selectedEndDay   = selectedStartDay   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    selectedEndMonth = selectedStartMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    selectedEndYear  = selectedStartYear  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);



    startDatePickerDialog =  new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            selectedStartYear = year;
            selectedStartMonth = monthOfYear;
            selectedStartDay = dayOfMonth;
            Log.e(TAG, "SET DATE: " + selectedStartYear + "/" + selectedStartMonth + "/" + selectedStartDay);

            btnStartDate.setText((selectedStartMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedStartDay + "/" + selectedStartYear);

            //set minimum date of end datepicker
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            endDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c2.getTime().getTime());

        }
    },selectedStartYear,selectedStartMonth,selectedStartDay);

    startDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);

    endDatePickerDialog =  new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            selectedEndYear = year;
            selectedEndMonth = monthOfYear;
            selectedEndDay = dayOfMonth;
            Log.e(TAG, "SET DATE: " + selectedEndYear + "/" + selectedEndMonth + "/" + selectedEndDay);

            btnEndDate.setText((selectedEndMonth+1)+"/"+selectedEndDay+"/"+selectedEndYear);


        }
    },selectedEndYear,selectedEndMonth,selectedEndDay);


    //set minimum date of end datepicker
    endDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTime().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am giving a demonstration below use this code.

this is class file.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Example extends Activity {

    private EditText startDate, endDate;
    private int selectedStartYear;

    private int selectedStartDay;
    private     int selectedStartMonth;
    private int selectedEndDay;
    private int selectedEndMonth;
    private int selectedEndYear;

    private     DatePickerDialog SecD, firstD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);



        startDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        endDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        selectedEndDay = selectedStartDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        selectedEndMonth = selectedStartMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        selectedEndYear = selectedStartYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        SecD = new DatePickerDialog(Pdf.this, new SecondDate(),
                selectedEndYear, selectedEndMonth, selectedEndDay);

        firstD = new DatePickerDialog(Pdf.this, new FirstDate(),
                selectedStartYear, selectedStartMonth, selectedStartDay);
        startDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                firstD.show();

            }
        });

        endDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SecD.show();

            }
        });

    }

    class FirstDate implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // Doing thing with first Date pick Dialog

            selectedStartYear = year;
            selectedStartMonth = monthOfYear;
            selectedStartDay = dayOfMonth;

            startDate.setText((selectedStartMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedStartDay
                    + "/" + selectedStartYear);

            // set minimum date of end datepicker
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c2.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            SecD.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c2.getTime().getTime());

        }

    }

    class SecondDate implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // Doing thing with second Date Picker Dialog

            selectedEndYear = year;
            selectedEndMonth = monthOfYear;
            selectedEndDay = dayOfMonth;

            endDate.setText((selectedEndMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedEndDay + "/"
                    + selectedEndYear);
        }

    }
}
```

and this is xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```